# Trying to install ruby 1.9.3 via rvm and fail at brew link apple-gcc42 on OS X 10.8.3

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm

I realize there are a long string of issues related to the new LLVM-based gcc with Xcode 4.2.

So I tried to `rvm get head`, `rvm install apple-gcc42`

Installation went fine but I am unable to `brew link apple-gcc42` it for following reasons:

```
Error: Could not symlink file: /usr/local/Cellar/apple-gcc42/4.2.1-5666.3/bin/i686-apple-darwin11-gfortran-4.2.1
Target /usr/local/bin/i686-apple-darwin11-gfortran-4.2.1 already exists. You may need to delete it.
To force the link and delete this file, do:
brew link --overwrite formula_name

To list all files that would be deleted:
 brew link --overwrite --dry-run formula_name
```

I am not sure if I should try `brew link --overwrite apple-gcc42` here. No reference on that `"Target /usr/local/bin/i686-apple-darwin11-gfortran-4.2.1 already exists"` error. Anyone can provide some ideas?

**My concern is whether it will impact anything related to Xcode 4.2.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not know that file then you can safely remove it - `/usr/local/bin/i686-apple-darwin11-gfortran-4.2.1` - as the name suggests it is for `fortran` which is not used in any standard software development now-days.

Comment: I think that gfortran is technically a dependency for scipy i believe? But may not impact anything like packaging an ios app i hope. Oh well, it shouldn't be that bad anyways.

Comment: So I used the command `rm '/usr/local/bin/gfortran'` and it worked for me now, thanks!